# Выборка из базы данных

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Есть пара табличек, в них содержится определенная информация (например: таблицы(cars,news)). Задача такова: я делаю поиск по сайту и не знаю, как сделать выборку из 2 или более таблиц, заранее благодарен.

p.s Хотелось бы узнать, как реализовать это на аяксе, то есть он ищет уже в процессе того, что ты написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так называемый "аякс" напрямую по бд не ищет, можно конечно сделать - CouchDB с рест интерфейсом, но не об этом.

```
SELECT * FROM cars JOIN news ON //... условие
```

Comment: баг какой-то с формат. кодом

Comment: на счет поиска - можно посмотреть еще на http://sphinxsearch.com/ ну если большой объем данных, на счет аякса в php увы не знаю, могу только общую архитектуру подсказать.

Comment: @boris Нужно пропустить строку между кодом и предыдущим абзацем.

Answer (score 1):

Создать файл ajax.php, сделать запрос к этому скрипту через javascript, jquery, prototype, mootools и т.д., как захочешь, тут же получить данные из бд по указанному выше методу, то есть джоин, и вернуть все в формате `echo json_encode($danniye)`, в самом скрипте сделать `evalJSON(true)`, сделать перебор `for in` и радоваться. ))

Comment: автора последнего поста на мыло ;)